# PythonTidy Integration in Coda?

Tags: python, editor, coda

Is there any way to integrate PythonTidy-like functionality directly in Coda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of October 2012, the answer to this question is "no".

Answer (score -1):

Python code is `tidy` by default, you just need to indent code blocks comparing with languages that have curly braces, and which need to be beautified if programmer don't like to write code by defined conventions.

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy/ - This is the kind of functionality I'm referring to.